# axios undefined in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I am having trouble with my axios import. In my TypeScript, I am importing it like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

But as soon as I want to use axios, the following error is returned:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

This is how I want to use axios:

```
const config = {
        baseURL: 'https://git.something.net/api/v4',
        headers: {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': 'IAMNOTTELLINGYOUTHIS'},
    }

const ac = axios.create(config);
```

axios version is `0.18.0`

Seems like the module is not really exporting the `default Axios;`

I have spent the last hours googeling and trying to fix it, but all I found was setting `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in the compilerOptions of my tsconfig.

I also had a peek at the axios.js and found these lines:

```
// Allow use of default import syntax in TypeScript
module.exports.default = axios;
```

To keep it short, I have absolutely no clue what I am doing wrong and would appreciate any help. If you need additional code or info, just let me know and I will try to provide the information.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's a bit weird, since `0.14` version, axios should have in also the full support for typescript, and there should be `default` export defined.

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought, too. I am very confused...

Comment: in a project I am using react + typescript with `"axios": "^0.18.0"` and this is how I do import it: `import axios, { AxiosStatic, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosPromise } from 'axios';` it all works like a charm

Comment: try to clear the npm cache and run a new npm install

Comment: unfortunately that did not help. made a `npm cache clear --force`, deleted the node_modules folder, run `npm install` again, nothing changed.
Maybe for extra information: I am trying to develop a rocket chat app and everything works fine during packaging and deployment, but fails during execution.

Comment: did you remove eventually your `package-lock.json` too? and how do you transpile the code?

Comment: yes, I tried that, didn't work either.
hm, I am not using a transpiler like babel (knowingly?), the compile target is set to `es2017`. Hope, that's what you meant. 
But also I am not sure what the rocket chat cli does with that code at the end of the day...

Comment: Getting the same issue.  Have you found any resolutions @user2240265?  I'm also not using any transpiler.  I wonder if Axios under typescript is meant to be transpiled by something like babel or weback (that is, the dist/axios.js isn't mean to work like an ES6 module)

Answer (score 1):

the answare from this post can help you out [Axios POST isn't running inside NodeJS/Express Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59881442/axios-post-isnt-running-inside-nodejs-express-route/61723773#61723773)

basically I posted there an es6 axios class that you can import by:

```
npm i @eneto/es6-axios-class

or

npm i es6-axios-class
```

you can find a very complete example here: https://github.com/EnetoJara/axios-typescript/blob/master/examples/userApi.ts

```js
import { AxiosError, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { Api } from './../src/api/api';
import { Credentials, Token, User } from './interfaces';

export class UserApi extends Api {
    public constructor (config?: AxiosRequestConfig) {
        super(config);


        // this middleware is been called right before the http request is made.
        this.interceptors.request.use((param: AxiosRequestConfig) => ({
            ...param,
        }));

        // this middleware is been called right before the response is get it by the method that triggers the request
        this.interceptors.response.use((param: AxiosResponse) => ({
            ...param
        }));

        this.userLogin = this.userLogin.bind(this);
        this.userRegister = this.userRegister.bind(this);
        this.getAllUsers = this.getAllUsers.bind(this);
        this.getById = this.getById.bind(this);
    }

    public userLogin (credentials: Credentials): Promise<Token> {
    }

    public userRegister (user: User): Promise<number> {
    }

    public async getAllUsers (): Promise<User[]> {
    }

    public getById (id: number): Promise<User> {
    }
}
```